# How to have server respond back to client browser that accesses server via alias URL

Tags: windows, redirect, iis, vbscript

Can't get serverside script to respond to client browser accessed via alias URL.

I have a web site with URL "abc.com" running on Windows Server.

I also have  other URL's -- lets call them "pqr.com" and "xyz.com" which are redirected to "abc.com" via CName records.

There is a web page on abc.com that has a form with two entry fields.
Filling in the fields and submitting the form sends control to the server where a vbscript obtains the inputs from the form and echoes them back to the user via Response.write commands.

I have added rewrite instuctions to the web.config file:

```xml
<system.webServer>

     <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="regex" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/abc.com" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
     </rewrite>

   </system.webServer>
```

When accessing the site using abc.com as the URL, things work fine. However, when using one of the aliases, the page with the form appears but nothing happens after hitting the submit button.  It's not clear if anything is being sent to the server or if the vbscript on the server is not getting the information sent back to the user's browser.

I have added rewrite instructions to the web.config file:

```xml
<system.webServer>

     <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="regex" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/abc.com" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
     </rewrite>

   </system.webServer>
```

I need the response to client browser accessing via alias URL to work just as when client accesses via non-alias URL.

Does HTTP Redirection need to be installed on the server?

Does the vbscript need to have some redirection code?

Are there any suggestions you can offer?

Thanks.

Comment: Clearly the data isn't getting to the server. If it was, the server would just write back to the same socket, and there is no reason why that wouldn't reach the client.

Comment: What is the form action value on your webpage?

Comment: It appears that user207421's comment is correct -- nothing is getting to the server, although I don't know how to confirm that other than there is no response.

Comment: @ Mohsin Mehmood  action="http://example.com/subscr-proc.asp"  method="post"

Comment: @Mohsin Mehmood previous comment deleted parts of the path.  http://example.com/subscr-proc.asp

Comment: @dancer Try setting the action url without domain name `action="subscrproc.asp"`